# oh my zsh geometry theme git errors

Tags: git, terminal, themes, oh-my-zsh

I recently installed a new theme on my iTerm with Oh My Zsh. When I started up my terminal, it seemed to be working well, but when I started to use git and switch from branch, I got an error:

```
_git_branch:4: parse error: condition expected: 1
__gitcomp_nl:compset:5: can only be called from completion function
__gitcomp_nl:compadd:6: can only be called from completion function
```

[image: here the errors in my terminal]

Here is the .zsh-theme file:

```
# Geometry
# Based on Avit and Pure
# avit: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/avit.zsh-theme
# pure: https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure

PROMPT_SYMBOL='▲'
EXIT_VALUE_SYMBOL="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}△%{$reset_color%}"
RPROMPT_SYMBOL='◇'

GIT_DIRTY="%{$fg[red]%}⬡%{$reset_color%}"
GIT_CLEAN="%{$fg[green]%}⬢%{$reset_color%}"
GIT_REBASE="\uE0A0"
GIT_UNPULLED="⇣"
GIT_UNPUSHED="⇡"

ZSH_THEME_GIT_TIME_SINCE_COMMIT_SHORT="%{$fg[green]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_TIME_SINCE_COMMIT_NEUTRAL="%{$fg[white]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_TIME_SINCE_COMMIT_LONG="%{$fg[red]%}"

_git_time_since_commit() {
  if [[ $(git log 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep -c "^fatal: bad default revision") == 0 ]]; then
    # Get the last commit.
    last_commit=$(git log --pretty=format:'%at' -1 2> /dev/null)
    now=$(date +%s)
    seconds_since_last_commit=$((now-last_commit))

    # Totals
    minutes=$((seconds_since_last_commit / 60))
    hours=$((seconds_since_last_commit/3600))

    # Sub-hours and sub-minutes
    days=$((seconds_since_last_commit / 86400))
    sub_hours=$((hours % 24))
    sub_minutes=$((minutes % 60))

    if [ $hours -gt 24 ]; then
      commit_age="${days}d"
      color=$ZSH_THEME_GIT_TIME_SINCE_COMMIT_LONG
    elif [ $minutes -gt 60 ]; then
      commit_age="${sub_hours}h${sub_minutes}m"
      color=$ZSH_THEME_GIT_TIME_SINCE_COMMIT_NEUTRAL
    else
      commit_age="${minutes}m"
      color=$ZSH_THEME_GIT_TIME_SINCE_COMMIT_SHORT
    fi
    echo "$color$commit_age%{$reset_color%}"
  fi
}

_git_branch() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || \
  ref=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "${ref#refs/heads/}"
}

_git_dirty() {
  if test -z "$(git status --porcelain --ignore-submodules)"; then
    echo $GIT_CLEAN
  else
    echo $GIT_DIRTY
  fi
}

_git_rebase_check() {
  git_dir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)
  if test -d "$git_dir/rebase-merge" -o -d "$git_dir/rebase-apply"; then
    echo "$GIT_REBASE"
  fi
}

_git_remote_check() {
  local_commit=$(git rev-parse @ 2>&1)
  remote_commit=$(git rev-parse @{u} 2>&1)
  common_base=$(git merge-base @ @{u} 2>&1) # last common commit

  if [[ $local_commit == $remote_commit ]]; then
    echo ""
  else
    if [[ $common_base == $remote_commit ]]; then
      echo "$GIT_UNPUSHED"
    elif [[ $common_base == $local_commit ]]; then
      echo "$GIT_UNPULLED"
    else
      echo "$GIT_UNPUSHED $GIT_UNPULLED"
    fi
  fi
}

_git_symbol() {
  echo "$(_git_rebase_check) $(_git_remote_check) "
}

_git_info() {
  if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$(_git_symbol)%F{242}$(_git_branch)%{$reset_color%} :: $(_git_time_since_commit) :: $(_git_dirty)"
  fi
}

_print_title() {
  print -n '\e]0;'
  print -Pn $1
  print -n '\a'
}

# Show current command in title
_set_cmd_title() {
  _print_title "${2} @ %m"
}

# Prevent command showing on title after ending
_set_title() {
  _print_title '%~'
}

geometry_prompt() {
  autoload -U add-zsh-hook

  add-zsh-hook preexec  _set_cmd_title
  add-zsh-hook precmd   _set_title

  PROMPT='
 %(?.$PROMPT_SYMBOL.$EXIT_VALUE_SYMBOL) %{$fg[blue]%}%3~%{$reset_color%} '

  PROMPT2=' $RPROMPT_SYMBOL '
  RPROMPT='$(_git_info)'
}

geometry_prompt
```

what the terminal spits out on the command:
[image: terminal spitouts]

Comment: Did you try running the command in `_git_branch()` and its components, `git symbolic-ref HEAD` and `git rev-parse --short HEAD`, on its own? Also, which versions of `zsh` and `git` are you using? (`zsh --version`; `git --version`)

Comment: updated the post for you hope this helps